# DNS blues with local vmware guest DC

Tags: networking, windows-10, vmware-workstation, windows-server-2003

I have a Windows 10 host with a VMWare workstation host-only adapter attached to a guest network(local workstations, not esx) with a super-vulnerable Windows 2003 DC we use to test network-security apps.

For obvious reasons the DC can never be actually connected to the Internet.  I have the host-only adapter priority set to something really high(`70`) and my WIFI adapter set to `23`.

For some reason my DNS keeps getting set to be resolved by the DC.  What happens is any time I'm working and I have my VMs up, I get crazy long DNS resolution which is annoying when browsing.  I ran a `route PRINT` and `23` is the top route for IPv4.  However, when I run `nslookup`, the default server says `192.168.73.11` which is the address of the vulnerable DC.

```
C:\Users\james>route PRINT
===========================================================================
Interface List
 27...3c 97 0e ce bd bc ......Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
 15...a4 4e 31 b7 35 61 ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
 20...a6 4e 31 b7 35 60 ......Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter
 21...0a 00 27 00 00 15 ......VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
 26...00 ff de 75 91 b6 ......TAP-Windows Adapter V9
  8...00 50 56 c0 00 08 ......VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8
 12...00 50 56 c0 00 01 ......VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1
 25...a4 4e 31 b7 35 60 ......Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6205
 14...3c 77 e6 ed ae 69 ......Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 30...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft Teredo Tunneling Adapter
 11...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
 31...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #5
 28...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #6
  6...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #8
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1      192.168.1.5     23
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0   192.168.73.253    192.168.73.44    100
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       192.168.1.5    279
      192.168.1.5  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.5    279
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.5    279
     192.168.33.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.33.1    266
     192.168.33.1  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.33.1    266
   192.168.33.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.33.1    266
     192.168.73.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.73.44    306
    192.168.73.44  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.73.44    306
   192.168.73.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.73.44    306
    192.168.239.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.239.1    276
    192.168.239.1  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.239.1    276
  192.168.239.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.239.1    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.33.1    266
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       192.168.1.5    279
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.73.44    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.239.1    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.33.1    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.5    279
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.73.44    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.239.1    276
===========================================================================
```

I truncated IPv6 output.

Then I run `nslookup` to prove the default dns server should be `192.168.1.1`, but instead it's pointing to the DC.

```
C:\Users\james>nslookup
Default Server:  dc1.ownme.local
Address:  192.168.73.11

>
```

Halp!

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Network Connections
2. Open "Properties" on the VMware adapter(s)
3. Select IPv4, "Properties".
4. Select "manually set DNS servers", keep both fields blank (if that doesn't work, try `0.0.0.0`).

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I don't want to do.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that can cause this issue:

1. The dns on the DC still points towards the wrong IP
2. The dns has not been flushed and is still using old entries.

If the windows 10 has a DHCP then the dns in the server options can also be pointed towards 192.168.73.11.

**Edit: The scope options must be set towards the right IP**

[image]

Can you tell me in the dns what the domain controller is pointed to?

Comment: The DNS of the DC is correct. It's just not connected to the internet so it can't route.  It's not a flushing issue.  The whole point is to get the correct DNS while still having automatic DHCP.

Comment: No thats not what I mean I mean in the DHCP options where u set the dns settings.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/GlXwL

Comment: Pretend that you go into work and you plug your laptop in.  They have no internet connection, but you connect your phone which does.  You have two nics.  You set the priority of your phone nic to 20 and your work to 70.  But your work's DNS still takes over.  Even though you should be routing through a nic that has absolutely nothing to do with your work.

Comment: Aah ok it seems the problem is a little more complicated than I thought.